# How to add object at array index in reducer

Tags: javascript, redux

I have store with arrays (`store.calendar[0].todos[{title: title, etc...}]`)

```
    0: {todos: Array(0)}
    1: {todos: Array(0)}
    2: {todos: Array(0)}
    3: {todos: Array(0)}
    4: {todos: Array(0)}
```

I need to add action object to the index todos of array:
I have tried with this reducer, but I get an error:

> state.calendar[newTodo.day].concat is not a function

My reducer:

```
let initialState = { calendar: []}

for (let i = 1; i <= 30; i++) {
  initialState.calendar.push({ todos: []});
}

const todosReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_TODO:
      const newTodo = action.todoItem;
      const newStore = {...state,
            todos: state.calendar[newTodo.day].concat(newTodo)};
      return newStore;
    default:
      return state
  }
}

export default todosReducer;
```

My action:

```
export const addTodoAction = (todoItem) => {
  return {
    type: ADD_TODO,
    todoItem
  }
}
```

My add todo function:

```
const handleSaveTodo = () => {
    props.addTodo({ 
      day: 5,
      title: trackInput.value,
      description: trackTextarea.value,
      completed: false
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You need to change your state in a totally immutable way.**

For this, you have to copy the calendar array, the day you are updating in this calendar and the todo list you are appending to.

First get the `day` and `todoItem`, you can use destructuring:

```
const { todoItem } = action;
const { day } = todoItem;
```

Then copy your calendar, you can use the spread syntax for that:

```
const calendar = [...state.calendar];
```

Then update the relevant day with a copy for that day, and append the new todo to the list of todos:

```
calendar[day] = { ...calendar[day], todos: [...calendar[day].todos, todoItem] };
```

Then return the updated state:

```
return { ...state, calendar };
```

Here is an example:

```js
const ADD_TODO = 'add-todo';

const initialState = { calendar: Array.from({ length: 30 }, (_, i) => ({ todos: [] })) };

const todosReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_TODO:
      const { todoItem } = action;
      const { day } = todoItem;
      const calendar = [...state.calendar];
      calendar[day] = { ...calendar[day], todos: [...calendar[day].todos, todoItem] };
      return { ...state, calendar };
    default:
      return state
  }
}

let state = initialState;

state = todosReducer(state, { type: ADD_TODO, todoItem: { day: 0, title: 'todo day 1' } });
state = todosReducer(state, { type: ADD_TODO, todoItem: { day: 1, title: 'todo day 2' } });
state = todosReducer(state, { type: ADD_TODO, todoItem: { day: 2, title: 'todo day 3' } });
state = todosReducer(state, { type: ADD_TODO, todoItem: { day: 2, title: 'second todo day 3' } });

console.log(state.calendar.slice(0, 3));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `state.calendar[newTodo.day].todo.concat(newTodo)` instead. I think you're trying to .concat() onto the object {todo: Array(0)} rather than the array within.

Answer (score -1):

you could try this:

Reducer:

```js
const initialState = { 
  calendar: Array.from({length: 30}, () => ({ todos: [] }))
}

const todosReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_TODO:
      const { todoItem } = action;
      const newCalendar = [...state.calendar];
      newCalendar[todoItem].todos.push(todoItem);
      
      return {
        ...state,
        calendar: newCalendar
      }
    default:
      return state
  }
}

export default todosReducer;
```